# Efficiency of numpy.dot with dynamic vs. static arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have to do a lot of *dot* products in my data processing pipeline. So, I was experimenting with the following two pieces of code where one is 3 times efficient (in terms of runtime) when compared to its slowest counterpart.

#### slowest method (with arrays created on the fly)

```
In [33]: %timeit np.dot(np.arange(200000), np.arange(200000, 400000)) 
352 µs ± 958 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### fastest method (with static arrays)

```
In [34]: vec1_arr = np.arange(200000) 
In [35]: vec2_arr = np.arange(200000, 400000) 

In [36]: %timeit np.dot(vec1_arr, vec2_arr) 
121 µs ± 90.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

why is the first method of *dynamically generating* arrays 3x slower when compared to second method? Is it because in the first method much of these extra time is spent in allocating memory for the elements? Or some other factors contributing to this degradation?

---

To gain little more understanding, I also replicated the setup in pure Python. And surprisingly there is no performance difference between doing it one way or the other, although it is slower than the numpy implementation, which is obvious and expected.

```
In [42]: %timeit sum(map(operator.mul, range(200000), range(200000, 400000)))
12.5 ms ± 71.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
In [38]: vec1 = range(200000) 
In [39]: vec2 = range(200000, 400000)

In [40]: %timeit sum(map(operator.mul, vec1, vec2)) 
12.5 ms ± 27.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The behaviour in the case of pure Python is clear because `range` function doesn't actually create all those elements. It does lazy evaluation (i.e. it is generated on the fly).

**Note**: The pure Python impl. is just to make myself convinced that the array allocation might be the factor that is causing the drag. It's not meant to compare it with NumPy implementation.

Comment: Regarding your first question, yeah, it's probably due to the allocation. Try timing just the allocation. All the sub-steps should all add up to ~350 µs. For further confirmation, even broadcasted arrays (which consume no additional memory) appear to take the same amount of time for element-wise operations (e.g. `+`) from some tests I did a while back. Perhaps the situation is different for dot products? I doubt it.

Comment: The first includes the time needed to create arrays, the large `arange`.  dynamic vs static isn't valid distinction in numpy.  The `dot` gets the same arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in speed is due to allocating the arrays in the slower case. I pasted the output of `%timeit` that takes into account the allocation of arrays in the two cases. The OP's timeit commands only took into account allocation in the slower case but not in the faster case.

```
%timeit np.dot(np.arange(200000), np.arange(200000, 400000)) 
# 524 µs ± 11.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit vec1_arr = np.arange(200000);  vec2_arr = np.arange(200000, 400000); np.dot(vec1_arr, vec2_arr) 
# 523 µs ± 17.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The allocation of both arrays takes about 360 microseconds on my machine, and the `np.dot` operation takes 169 microseconds. The sum of those two durations is 529 microseconds, which is equivalent to the output of `%timeit` output above.

```
%timeit vec1_arr = np.arange(200000);  vec2_arr = np.arange(200000, 400000)
# 360 µs ± 16.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

vec1_arr = np.arange(200000) 
vec2_arr = np.arange(200000, 400000) 

%timeit np.dot(vec1_arr, vec2_arr) 
# 169 µs ± 5.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pure Python test is not fair. Because `np.arange(200000)` really returns an array while `range(200000)` only returns a generator. So these two methods both create arrays on the fly.

```
import operator

%timeit sum(map(operator.mul, range(200000), range(200000, 400000)))
# 15.1 ms ± 45.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

vec1 = range(200000)
vec2 = range(200000, 400000)
%timeit sum(map(operator.mul, vec1, vec2)) 
# 15.2 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

vec1 = list(range(200000))
vec2 = list(range(200000, 400000))

%timeit sum(map(operator.mul, vec1, vec2)) 
# 12.4 ms ± 716 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And we can see the time cost on allocation:

```
import numpy as np

%timeit np.arange(200000), np.arange(200000, 400000)
# 632 µs ± 9.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.dot(np.arange(200000), np.arange(200000, 400000)) 
# 703 µs ± 5.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

vec1_arr = np.arange(200000) 
vec2_arr = np.arange(200000, 400000) 

%timeit np.dot(vec1_arr, vec2_arr) 
# 77.7 µs ± 427 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Make sense.